# Optimise MySQL insert of XML data feed

Tags: mysql, sql

I take a XML feed from a company nightly and need some serious optimization as it's taking forever

Code below shows how I do it but there must be a better way - basically, I'm taking in each product, then associated retailers who supply that product

```
//db connect
include '../php/lib/dbconnect.inc';

$categories = array(1, 2, 4, 8, 9);

foreach ($arr as $key => $cat_id) { {

$url = "http://*********.com/feed?f=PRSP_UK_xx&categories=$cat_id&limit=100&startproducts=$ii&price_min=0.01&sortproducts=score&show=properties";
$c = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "****:****");
$xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($c));
curl_close($c);

$num_items = $xml->{'product-count'};

$ii = 0;

while ($ii <= $num_items) { // this sets the number of items from start of xml feed

    $url = "http://********.com/feed?f=PRSP_UK_xx&categories=$cat_id&limit=100&startproducts=$ii&price_min=0.01&sortproducts=score&show=properties";

    $c = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "****:****");
    $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($c));
    curl_close($c);

// load each product first

    foreach ($xml->product as $products) {

$title = $products->name;

$title = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/i', '', $title);

$PRid = $products->id;

$author = $products->properties->group->property[2]->value;

$author = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/i', '', $author);

$genre = $products->properties->group->property[4]->value;

$genre = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/i', '', $genre);

$prodcat = $products->{'category'};

$prodcat = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/i', '', $prodcat);

$prodcatID = $products->{'category-id'};

$lowprice = $products->{'lowest-price'};

$highprice = $products->{'highest-price'};

$imageURL = $products->{'image-url'};

$userrating = $products->rating[0]->average;

$userrating = str_replace(",",".",$userrating);

$profrating = $products->rating[0]->average;

$profrating = str_replace(",",".",$profrating);

    $addline = mysql_query("
    insert into PRprodINFO (
    PRid,
    main_category,
    title,
    author,
    genre,
    prodcat,
    prodcatID,
    userrating,
    profrating,
    lowprice,
    highprice,
    imageURL
    )
        VALUES (
    '$PRid',
    'Books',
    '$title',
    '$author',
    '$genre',
    '$prodcat',
    '$prodcatID',
    '$userrating',
    '$profrating',
    '$lowprice',
    '$highprice',
    '$imageURL'
    ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lowprice='$lowprice', highprice='$highprice'",$db);

    if(!$addline) { echo "cannot add to table here".mysql_error(); exit; } // debug

    // now each retailer associated with the product

    foreach ($products->retailer as $retailer) {

    $id = $retailer->{'id'};

    $name = $retailer->{'name'};

    $name = addslashes($name);

    $link = $retailer->{'link'};

    $logoURL = $retailer->{'logo'};

    $stockinfo = $retailer->{'stock-info'};

    $price = $retailer->{'price'};

    $priceshipmin = $retailer->{'price-with-shipping-min'};

    $priceshipmax = $retailer->{'price-with-shipping-max'};

    $dummyid = $PRid.$id;

    $id = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/i', '', $id);

    $stockinfo = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/i', '', $stockinfo);

    $dummyid = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/i', '', $dummyid);

    $addretail = mysql_query("
    insert into PRretailerinfo (
    PRid,
    id,
    dummyid,
    category_id,
    name,
    link,
    logoURL,
    stockinfo,
    price,
    priceshipmin,
    priceshipmax
    )
        VALUES (
    '$PRid',
    '$id',
    '$dummyid',
    '$i',
    '$name',
    '$link',
    '$logoURL',
    '$stockinfo',
    '$price',
    '$priceshipmin',
    '$priceshipmax'
    ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price='$price', priceshipmin='$priceshipmin', priceshipmax='$priceshipmax'",$db);

    if(!$addretail) { echo "cannot add to table - price is".$price.mysql_error(); exit; } // debug

} // close
} // close

    // add 100 to url to get next 100 items
$ii = ($ii+100);

}

} // whole thing
```

I would presume there is a much better way to do this than line by line as the whole thing is approx 800,000 products and, on average, 4 retailers for each product

I believe its quicker to construct a long query first using mulitple lines before inserting but I can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The slowness very likely isn't due to issuing multiple insert queries, but instead very likely due to the huge number of http requests you're making to get the data.  Is there any way you can get more data back from the server at once?

....Maybe changing your product fetch parameter from limit=100 to limit=$num_items

Considering your comment, I guess you could try speeding things up a bit by using separate threads - one to download the content, and one to insert into your table.  That way you are always getting new data, rather than getting, then waiting for inserts to finish, then getting more.  Coding may become quite a bit more complex, though.

Comment: I guessed that as well, no, they limit it to 100

Comment: Thanks Jake but that's prob a bit out of my league! Thanks again for your comments/suggestions

Comment: Well... you could theoretically have completely separate tasks that are performing the different functions - don't really need to use "official" threading, if that is a daunting idea.  Just start one process that does nothing but fetch data constantly, saving the results to a local folder.  Have the other task also running, watching the same folder for new files.  Simple, really.

Comment: Ah ok, so i could pull it down in 100s and save the files, can that be done with PHP, easily? The file naming and saving etc... is there then a way to merge XML files? Then Once down I could run the insert which must surely be faster - any code snippets you can help with? If not I can post another question on here from that angle.

Comment: Another question may be in order

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do a multi record insert and still use mysql's on duplicate key update feature...

Try to disable the indexes in the table you're inserting into. Otherwise mysql has to modify the indexes after each insert, when you really only need to do it once at the end. Prepared statments should pick up a the speed a tiny bit too.

Use microtime() to find the slow part of your script. The database performance probably isnt significant compared to the network io(downloading).